# Compare strings using HashMap

Tags: java, xml

I have few xml files like this

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<note>
<to>Tim</to>
<from>Joe</from>
<head>About Job</head>
</note>

<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<note>
<to>Tim</to>
<from>Joe</from>
<head>How are u?</head>
</note>

 <?xml version = "1.0"?>
<note>
<to>Marry</to>
<from>Pit</from>
<head>Welcome to home</head>
</note>
```

I parsing this files and store data into the text file like this

```
FROM: 
   Tim
   Tim
   Pit
TO: 
   Joe
   Joe
   Marry
HEAD: 
   About Job
   How are u?
   Welcome to home
```

**I want the names are not repeated**
How i can do it with hasMap, please help me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need a unique Collection of names, use a `HashSet<String>`. Only one instance would be stored for each unique name. `HashMap` would make sense if you want each unique name to serve as key. In that case you must decide what you want to store as the value for each name key.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks like you only need to store a collection of unique objects. Implementations of `Set` will help. You can use a `HashSet` of `String` objects:

`Set uniqueNames = new HashSet<String>()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> from = new HashSet<String>();
```

You simply add new records with add method. Remember that set will not keep order in witch elements hav been inserted. But I suppose in your example you will sort names before printing, so it's ok.

If you want keep the iteration order use LinkedHashSet instead.

Answer (score 0):

Read the text file and store the same into a `HashSet` like

```
Set names = new HashSet<String>();
names.put(nameString);
```

Above solution is `case-sensitive` - it means `Tim` and `tim` will be treated differently. Covert the name strings to lower case using `"nameString".toLowerCase()` before putting it into the `HashSet`  if you are looking for `case-insensitive` behavior like

```
names.put(nameString.toLowerCase());  \\now Tim and tim will be treated equally
```

Hope this helps.